# Color a block in header

Tags: html, css, frameworks, jekyll

I want to split up my header bar with a green block (approx. 1/4 of length of header) and have the rest a light brow. Now I have a title and the background-color setting only colors the actual content, how can I color the whole left side of the bar the encompass the title?

html:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<header class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="n-logo" href="/">That Awkward Moment.</a>
            <ul class="n-menu">
                <li><a href="#flav">The Project</a></li>
                <li><a href="#feat">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#inst">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#vid">Github</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
</html>
```

and the css for it (sry their might be mistakes, I know, I just want the colored block):

```
body {
    background-color: $yellowLighter;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
}

header {
    display: block;
}

h1 {
    color: $orangeDarker;
}

.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.nav {
    padding: 1em 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background: #fffcf5;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

.n-menu {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.n-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1.2em;
}
.n-menu a {
    color: #555;
}

.n-logo {
    float: left;
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

li {
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the part that should be colored green. Do you mean the part of the container that contains the "n-logo" link?

Comment: It would have to be the entire left side of the header including the title, but now it's either just the text background(too small) or the whole header container (too large), if you saw it you woul d understand.

Answer (score 0):

I combine your html and css, try the following:

```
<html>
<header class="nav">
    <style>
body {
    background-color: $yellowLighter;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    margin: auto auto;
}

header {
    display:block;
}

h1 {
    color: $orangeDarker;
}

.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.nav {
    padding: 0 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background: #fffcf5;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

.n-menu {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.n-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1.2em;
}
.n-menu a {
    color: #555;
}

.n-logo {
    position: absolute;
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.n-logo-div{
    background-color:green;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

li {
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}   
    </style>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="n-logo-div">
                <a class="n-logo" href="/">That Awkward Moment.</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="n-menu">
                <li><a href="#flav">The Project</a></li>
                <li><a href="#feat">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#inst">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#vid">Github</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
</html>
```